# HS22 10 GB network

Tags: ibm, fibre-channel, 10gbethernet, lenovo, hs22

I want to switch from 1 GB ethernet connection to 10 GB on HS22 blades which are installed in a H chassis.

On the storage side, I have installed 8GB FC cards which are connected via the MSIM to a 8 GB FC switch to LENOVO DAS servers. Everything is fine, I am satisfied with the performance of this setup.

But on the network side, I need a boost so I trying to find a way to upgrade to 10 GB but I find it hard to find information on the equipment needed or even if is possible.

Anyone with experience that can give me some tips? I know the HS22 are old but I found some hardware brokers that still carry parts for them but I need to know what to ask them.

Thanks,
Chris